# Issue with razor pay OAuth connect flow

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth, payment, razorpay

Currently i am adding feature to connect razorpay merchants on my site using https://razorpay.com/docs/oauth/authorize/#authorization-url

and generating url to redirect merchants for login and permission on below URL
[https://auth.razorpay.com/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/admin-home&scope=read_only&state=NOBYtv8r6c75ex6WZ](https://auth.razorpay.com/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/admin-home&scope=read_only&state=NOBYtv8r6c75ex6WZ)

Note: client id is generated and downloaded from https://dashboard.razorpay.com/app/keys page

but when above URL is opening in new window it gives below error

can someone please help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether you have whitelisted the redirect_uri, as per the instructions.

It is highly possible that there are validation placed based on the whitelisting which is preventing you request from going through.

It is explained in Step 1 on the same documentation which you have gone through.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as i checked i can not see 'Applications' menu under 'Partner' menu in razor pay dashboard. even if account is 100% activated. can you please help me how can i get that menu item ?

Comment: @UmeshGoti - Pls check with Razorpay support team, if you are an activated user but not getting relevant options on dashboard. As per the documentation, whitelisting the uri is mandatory on development client.